# how I can get the value of url in <p> tag in html

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I want the value of the id which is in url in html paragraph tag. How I do this

**jquery**

```
 function get_Table_List(id) {
       $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "one.html?outlet="+id,
               });
```

**html**

```
<div class="outletTitle" style="text-align:center;">Selected outlet:<p id="preview"></p> 
</div>
```

Comment: What are you doing with the Ajax response? You're calling `$.ajax()` but there's no success handler defined.

Comment: can you share code in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding, using `.text()` you change the text value.

```
function get_Table_List(id) {
   $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "one.html?outlet="+id,
       });
   $('#preview').text(id); // where changes takes place
}
```

**Result:**

```
 Selected outlet:<p id="preview">id</p>
```

Or if you want to change the `id` of the `P` tag then `.prop()` is in.

```
$('#preview').prop('id', id);
```

**Result:**

```
Selected outlet:<p id=id></p>
```

Comment: suppose in url outlet i m having cal like these "one.html?outlet=CAL" that CAL will be print in my html program like these selected outlet:CAL i want these answer but it is not cuming frm ur code

Comment: thanx but i m nt getting the answer

Comment: @Atul sorry remove '' in the braces edited my answer try now `$('#preview').text(id);`

Comment: @Atul I'm glad that I was able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
var $temp = $('p').html();
alert($temp);

});
</script>
```

[Demo](http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/jQuery/jQuery-get-tag-value.html)

Answer (score 0):

`var x = $('outletTitle p').attr('id')` should do

then do what ever you want to do with the variable

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question clearly.

Did you mean when someone requests `one.html?outlet=123`, you want that page `one.html` shows the outlet id in your `<p id="preview"></p>` tag?

If this is the case, I think you have to parse `document.location.href`.